# Why it Printing out different name? in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to Print all the result same.
my code:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='category')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py:

```
        excludeCompanyId = []
        company = Company.objects.all().order_by('?').exclude(id__in=excludeCompanyId)[:1]#random 1 company
        companyName = company[0].name
        print(companyName)

        companyProduct = Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('?')[:10]
        print(companyProduct[0].company)

        for i in companyProduct:
            print(i.company)
```

Result will be different at different time.

But I want to show you one result:

```
Tesla
Apple Inc.
Sony
Sony
Sony
Sony
```

**I want to print all the result same.** how do i do that?

Comment: And what do you suppose `.order_by('?')` does? Well it orders the queryset randomly so if you write that intentionally I don't know anything that can solve your problem.

Comment: @ Abdul Aziz Barkat , then how can i get a random company?

Comment: with that random company, i want to get first 10 product of Product model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.order_by('?')` orders the queryset *randomly*. But it seems you do want a random `Company`, the real problem here is that you don't actually use the random company you get and reuse the QuerySet instead effectively making a subquery.

Below is a copy of your code with comments to explain what exactly goes **wrong**:

```py
excludeCompanyId = []
company = Company.objects.all().order_by('?').exclude(id__in=excludeCompanyId)[:1] 
# company here is not an instance of a company it is a QuerySet

companyName = company[0].name # You make a query when you write `company[0]` but note `company` remains unevaluated
print(companyName)

companyProduct = Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('?')[:10]
# You write `filter(company=company)`
# This effectively makes a subquery, meaning for each row in `Product`
# a random `Company` is selected if this company is the same as the products
# company then the product is selected
print(companyProduct[0].company)
```

What you need to do is *actually* evaluate the query and get a product and use that in your other query. Also instead of the slice `[:1]` simply use [`.first()` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first):

```py
excludeCompanyId = []
company = Company.objects.all().order_by('?').exclude(id__in=excludeCompanyId).first() 

if company is None:
    # there are no matching companies return something appropriate here
print(company.name)

companyProduct = Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('?')[:10]
for i in companyProduct:
    print(i.company.name)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. it works. May Allah help you.